# Optimizing coldfusion resources for scheduled tasks

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I've been tasked with optimizing some scheduled tasks that run for hours. One of the tasks runs through data from 1995-present. My first thought (besides revising queries,etc) was to create a cfloop through all the years and start a thread for each year.

Is this a good approach? Is there a better way to divide up the workload on such a task?

Comment: I would start by looking for a way to restrict the data being processed to only that which has been changed since the last time the job was run.  Next, I would see whether or not the jobs could be transferred from ColdFusion to a database scheduled job.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to work out what is slow before you optimize anything. Otherwise you may spend a lot of time tweaking code for relatively small gains. Databases are often the bottleneck but you need to find that out first.

At a simple level, you can enable debugging (on a dev machine) and see where time is being spent. There are also tools like Fusion Reactor which will give you more insight. Alternatively you can can just add some `<cflog>` calls to your script and then analyze them to identify the slow blocks. Which ever way you decide to do it, you need to know where your effort is best spent.

Some other thoughts....

- Does the data change?

If not then compile the data once and store it so that the scheduled tasks don't have to redo the work each time

- Which version of CF are you on?

You could run out of threads if you are not careful - which would be particularly bad if your server is running other stuff. But yes, threads could be part of your solution.

Comment: I'm on CF10. I had thought of checking if the data is changed, unfortunately the database isn't well-kept.  It might be the best thing I can do is petition the company who manages it to add a last_changed column to the data.

Comment: CF Standard edition has a restricted number of threads. Think adding that column would be a good idea - good luck :)

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - Yes, sounds like being able to identify added/changed data *only* would do more to improve the process than anything else.